If R2 is not appropriate for non-linear ML algorithms such as Random Forests, can a Pearson or Spearman correlation be used as performance metric?
$R^2$ is not appropriate for non-linear models, such as Random Forest (RFs) models.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03063

Is R-squared truly an invalid metric for non-linear models?

https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/r-squared-invalid-nonlinear-regression/

Using $R^2$ for RF


$R^2$ can be considered an extension of Pearson Correlation coefficient, whereby if you square Pearson $r$, $r^2 \equiv R^2$.
Is it reasonable to use Pearson $r$ or Spearman $\rho$ or Kendall's $\tau$ as correlation coefficients to denote the correspondence between test/true and predicted values in outcome in the absence of using $R^2$? Is the main issue with using $R^2$ is that the assumptions of $R^2$ and residuals do not hold in nonlinear applications, but that a Spearman $\rho$ (a non-parametric correlation coefficient) could be acceptable or reasonable to use?

If $R^2$ isn't valid, taking the square root won't make it so.

This question seems to be based on an incorrect premise that $R^2$ is invalid in nonlinear models.

An answer to this heavily depends on your understanding of 'appropriate'. And for what exactly should it be appropriate? Fitting, evaluation...

First, note that $R^2$ is not an invalid measure of performance for nonlinear models. Let's look at the equation.
$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$
The numerator of the fraction is exactly the square loss, which is a rather standard criterion to optimize, and this calculation gives the $R^2$ as a monotonic transformation of the square loss.
This argument makes no reference to how the predicted $\hat y_i$ values arise, if they comes from linear models, nonlinear models, machine learning models, regularized models, random forests, neural networks, support vector regressions, asking people to give their wildest guesses, or simulating random numbers. That's simply what the calculation means, a transformation of the square loss.
Consequently, this calculation is as legitimate as mean squared error or root mean squared error when it comes to evaluating performance. Sure, there is a possibility to overfit and fail to catch that overfitting when you evaluate in-sample, so do an out-of-sample calculation like I discuss here.
If you use Pearson or Spearman correlation to evaluate your predictions, you run into a major issue that $y = (1, 2, 3)$ and $\hat y = (15, 17, 19)$ have perfect Pearson and Spearman correlations, yet $\hat y$ represents terrible predictions of $y$. The $R^2$ calculation given above detects that by returning a value below zero (worse than a reasonable benchmark of always predicting the marginal mean to be the conditional mean). Pearson or Spearman correlation between $y$ and $\hat y$ will miss that the predictions are terrible.
Such a correlation calculation could be a useful measure of how well the model is able to distinguish between distinct outcomes, same as ROCAUC or PRAUC in a "classification" problem gives a sense of how well the model can discern between the two categories (this is what another answer means about Somers' D, which is equivalent to ROCAUC in that setting), but such a correlation calculation can miss certain ways in which the predicted and true values differ, possibly differences of concern to you.
So while the question starts off by assuming that $R^2$ is illegitimate for nonlinear models and speculates that correlation might be useful, the reality is that $R^2$ is perfectly legitimate for nonlinear models, while correlation has problems (but might be useful when you understand its limitations).
(And if you dislike that $R^2$ is an in-sample measure of performance, so is correlation when you calculate it in-sample.)
For more on how $R^2$ is a comparison to a benchmark, perhaps refer to Gneiting & Resin (2023), which I recently found, particularly their equations (31) and (32) where they develop the notion of what they call a "universal coefficient of determination".
REFERENCE
Gneiting, Tilmann, and Johannes Resin. "Regression diagnostics meets forecast evaluation: Conditional calibration, reliability diagrams, and coefficient of determination." Electronic Journal of Statistics 17.2 (2023): 3226-3286.

I would argue that ordinal correspondence between the predicted and observed values is indeed a reasonable way to express the performance of a non-linear model. It is in fact common to see Somers' D used for this purpose.
However, whatever measure you end up using, you are still expressing the training error (i.e., the performance on the sample used to fit the model). For prediction purposes, it is better to try and obtain a measure of out-of-sample performance. You can achieve this through cross-validation or bootstrapping.
